# Python Popen - env - ffmpeg crash

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, environment-variables, popen

I am trying to run an ffmpeg command on Windows 7 (python 2.7) which runs on command line just fine, but the `env` of my `Popen` is not working.
Here is the working command line:

```
SET FFREPORT=level=48:file=C\:\\temp\\TESTFFMPEGOUTPUT.txt && C:\Temp\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i “I:\somefolder\testInput.mov" "I:\somefolder\testOutput.mov"
```

And here is my current python code:

```
ffreport = "level=48:file={}".format(self.logFilePath) + " && "
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
self.process1 = Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo, shell=False, env={'SET FFREPORT':ffreport})
```

This results in windows reporting "ffmpeg has stopped working".
Not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
command = r"C:\Temp\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i I:\somefolder\testInput.mov I:\somefolder\testOutput.mov"

self.process1 = Popen(
        shlex.split(command), shell=False, 
        env=dict(FFREPORT="level=48:file=C\:\\temp\\TESTFFMPEGOUTPUT.txt"))
```

Comment: This gives the error - WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified. I still would like to find a way to use the Popen command as is and fix the env.

Comment: Windows `CreateProcess` takes a command-line string, so there's no point to creating a list with `shlex.split(command)`. Modify a copy of the current environment: `environ = os.environ.copy();` `environ['FFREPORT'] = 'level=48:file={}'.format(self.logFilePath);` `self.process1 = Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo, env=environ)`. It defaults to `shell=False`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun, this works great, fixed. If you could do this as an answer I will mark it up as the answer.

Comment: I now have the same sort of issue once I added in another pre command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879485/popen-set-env-parameter

Answer (score -1):

How about this? 
using `os.startfile(path[, operation])`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile